# Using npm to install or update required packages just like bundler for rubygems

Tags: javascript, dependencies, node.js, bundler, npm

I love [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), it's great at dependency management.  I love [npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm), installing node packages is easy!  I have a nodejs app and would love to be **able to specify my apps dependencies and easily install / update them** wherever I deploy my app. This isn't a library I'm releasing, it's a full fledged web-app.

I'm aware of the `npm bundle` command, but that just seems to simply override the directory where packages are installed.

I'm used to using bundler in this fashion:

```
# Gemfile
gem "rails", "3.0.3"
```

Installs rails v3.0.3 and any other required gems on the host machine only if it doesn't already exist

```
> bundle install
```

**How can I achieve something similar with npm?**

Comment: is my answer not what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

As of npm 1.0 (which is now what you get by default if you follow the steps in the README file), "bundle" is no longer a segregated thing -- it's just "how it works".

So:

1. Put a `package.json` file in the root of your project
2. List your deps in that file

   ```
   { "name" : "my-project"
   , "version" : "1.0.0"
   , "dependencies" : { "express" : "1.0.0" } }
   ```
3. `npm install`  Since you're calling this with no args, and not in global mode, it'll just install all your deps locally.
4. `require("express")` and be happy.

Comment: When in production, I highly recommend changing the local `your_app/node_modules` directory to a symlink outside your app directory.  You don't want to have to download, build, and install each dependency every time you deploy.

Comment: Ok. what if I forget to update my package.json? Is there any way to force NPM to look not for package.json but for packages I am using in my code?

Comment: This is not quite correct.  NPM will install all the dependencies for the above `my-project` in `./node_modules/my-project/node_modules`.  I'm not sure if there is a convenient way to have it install all the dependencies in `./node_modules`  Anyone?

Comment: @DanielBeardsley I don't think that's how npm works.  If you're seeing that behavior, and you can reproduce it, please post an issue on the npm github page.

Comment: Oh, no \n in SO comments, I guess.  For your other issue, I recommend checking your node_modules folder into git, and not using `npm install` as part of the deploy.  `npm rebuild` can re-compile binary deps.  @Pono - No, npm doesn't read your code, or your mind.  It strictly does what you tell it in package.json, configs, and the cli commands. :)

Comment: Agree with @DanielBeardsley. I suffer from that behavior even with npm 1.1.70

Answer (score 11):

### Edit: This only applies to npm versions < 1.0

---

It was quite difficult to figure this out, but **NPM makes this possible**.

#### You need three components

1. A subdirectory in your repository (i.e. `deps/`)
2. A `package.json` file in the above directory that lists dependencies
3. An `index.js` file in the above directory that requires your dependencies

### Example

*Imagine that [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) is your only dependency*

#### deps/package.json

*note:* Increment the version # each time you modify the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "myapp_dependencies",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies":{
    "express": "2.0.0beta2"
  }
}
```

#### deps/index.js

```
export.modules = {
  express: require('express')
  //add more
}
```

Now you should be able to install your dependencies using npm.  You could even make this part of your deployment process

```
cd deps
npm install
```

Then within your app code you can get access to your specific version of express like this:

```
var express = require('myapp_dependencies').express;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best method I've seen so far. However, wouldn't  the `require('express')` in deps/index.js just import the latest express version, and not necessarily the one we installed? I'm a nodeJS noob so please bear with me.

Comment: No, that's the magic of `npm install`, it adds symlinks within the directory of your installed package to the correct versions of dependent packages.  When your dependencies package is required, the `require('express')` checks the local directory first and finds the symlink to the correct version of express.

Answer (score 5):

You should read these two articles from Isaacs(author npm) blog. I think they are really good, and I believe tell you how to achieve your goal:

1. http://blog.izs.me/post/1675072029/10-cool-things-you-probably-didnt-realize-npm-could-do
2. http://foohack.com/2010/08/intro-to-npm/

I believe link #1(point #11) explains this:

> ## 11: Bundle all your dependencies into the package itself
>
> When you use the
> npm bundle command, npm will put all
> your dependencies into the
> node_modules folder in your package.
> But it doesn’t stop there.
>
> If you want to depend on something
> that’s not on the registry, you can do
> that. Just do this:
>
> npm bundle install
> http://github.com/whoever/whatever/tarball/master
> This will install the contents of that
> tarball into the bundle, and then you
> can list it as a dependency, and it
> won’t try to install it when your
> package gets installed.
>
> This also is handy if you have your
> own fork of something, and would
> prefer not to change the name.
>
> In fact, you can run almost any npm
> command at the bundle. To see what’s
> inside, you can do npm bundle ls. To
> remove something, do npm bundle rm
> thing. And, of course, you can install
> multiple versions and activate the one
> you want.

Comment: This is useful, though it wasn't what I was looking for.  Perhaps I need to add clarification.  I'm looking for a way to automatically install or update (on the destination machine) the NPM packages my app depends on whenever I deploy it.  It looks like `npm bundle` is used to collect all your dependencies into a specific directory other than the default.  I'll probably come up with my own solution that performs similarly to `bundle install` (`bundler` for ruby)

Comment: Just a note, since `npm` version 1.0+, `npm bundle` has been removed. Instead, just use the `npm install` command with no package name, it'll read the package.json and pull down the required packages.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the simplest solution is to use a `package.json` file with the `private` flag (added to npm just last month) set to `true`. That way, you can run `npm install` or `npm bundle` to grab your project's dependencies, but you prevent anyone from accidentally publishing your non-public project.

Here's an example `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "yourProject"
,"version": "1.0.0"
,"dependencies": { "express" : ">=2.1.0" }
,"private": true
}
```

Running `npm install` will install `express` on the local system if it doesn't already exist; running `npm publish` gives an error because of the `"private": true`.

You and your team can use the version tag internally to track dependency changes over time—each time you change a dependency, bump the version. To see which version you've installed, use `npm ls installed`.

Comment: I think you shouldn't quote `true` and that it's only working because strings are truthy values (that is, `!!"false" === true`).

Answer (score 2):

As of Npm version 1.1.2 , there's a new command [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html) which creates an `npm-shrinkwrapped.json` file, analogous to `Gemfile.lock`. It's important to make one, to prevent software rot (see [Bundler's rationale](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html)). Particularly as Nodejs has such a fast moving community.

While `bundle install` creates a `Gemfile.lock` automatically, `npm install` won't create `npm-shrinkwrapped.json` (but will use it when it exists). Hence you need to remember to use `npm shrinkwrap`.

Read a full guide at http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/

Answer (score 1):

Publish your app with `npm` as well, and list its dependencies in your package.json file.

When someone uses `npm` to install your package, `npm` will take care of resolving its dependencies.

Packages spec: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.0

Comment: Yeah, but this is a non-opensource web app. If you have an idea that doesn't involve publishing the app, please edit your answer or create another one.

Comment: Then publish a package like "myapp-dependencies" that your users can use `npm` to install prior to installing your app. I don't think there's any other `gem` equivalent for node.js.